# SQL authentication Windows application

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am developing a Winforms application (in VS2017 - VB.net) which connects to a Microsoft Azure SQL database by SQL authentication (connection string builder). The plan is to set up a new SQL database for each new customer as it is easier to manage (backups, deleting DB should the customer leave etc).  The customer would be set up as a contained user on their database and would be the only one logging onto that database. I will be the only one managing the overview SQL server.

Should the customer be set up in Active Directory instead of sales authentication? I read it is more secure, but not sure if this option is best for my application.  There could be many different operating systems, locations, customer domain settings etc. that I would not know in advance.  Ideally, my application is generic and each customer would enter in their credentials to connect to their database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stay using SQL Authentication, because Azure SQL Authentication is intended for single tenant applications (applications intended to use for a single organization) or for software-as-a-service applications.

In your scenario you can make use of Elastic Pools where you can apply schema changes and upgrade your database with just one elastic job, if all your customer will use the same database schema. This should reduce time and effort of having to deal with many versions of databases for your customers, and having more personnel providing support to the many versions of databases and applications to your customers. Elastic pools only support SQL Authentication.